# How to use AGI function SAY DIGITS and reads from a variable in Perl

Tags: perl, asterisk, perl-module, agi

The SAY DIGITS function in Perl does not read from a variable that contains the STDOUT result from a command line executed in Perl, but it works when i assign any value to the variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $Hour = qx(date "+%I"); 

print "SAY DIGITS $Hour \"\"\n";
```

The extensions.conf file:

```
exten => 222,1,Answer()
exten => 222,2,AGI(time.sh)
exten => 222,3,Hangup()
```

The code should tell the caller the current time. simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `qx(...)` (and backticks and [`readpipe`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#readpipe%5d) usually has a newline appended to it, and you usually want to `chomp` that value before you use it downstream.

```
my $Hour = qx(date "+%I"); 
chomp($Hour);

print "SAY DIGITS $Hour \"\"\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the [Lingua::ENG::Numbers](http://search.cpan.org/~petamem/Lingua-ENG-Numbers-0.1106/) module on CPAN.

Lingua::ENG::Numbers converts numeric values into their English string equivalents.

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Lingua::ENG::Numbers;
my $hour       = 0 + qx(date "+%I"); 
my $minute     = 0 + qx(date "+%M");
my $hour_str   = "";
my $minute_str = "";


if(my $o = Lingua::ENG::Numbers->new($hour)) {
    $hour_str = $o->get_string;
};
if(my $o = Lingua::ENG::Numbers->new($minute)) {
    $minute_str = $o->get_string;
};

print "It's $hour_str $minute_str";
```

You will get an output like `It's Seven Seventeen` (that's the time on my timezone).

Should you need to get audio from that you can pipe it through [espeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) which is a speech synthesizer for English and other languages.

UPDATE: Ah, I see, so `SAY DIGITS` is already implemented in Asterisk.

Comment: yes SAY DiGITS is already a function in AGI. Thanks for your help anyway.